# Defining the length of bluetooth discovery on Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

I see that the discovery of nearby Bluetooth devices (inquiry) on Android takes 12s. Is there a way to shorten this to, say, 6s?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cancel the discovery cancelDiscovery() once you have found what you are looking for.